# Как установить cookie из ответа API (set-cookie ) который находится на другом домене?

Tags: php, reactjs, api, cookie

Нужно сохранить сессию, которая приходит в set-cookie ответа API.

Я делаю запрос с **https**://localhost:3000 к API https://domain/api/get_phones. Мне приходит ответ (заголовки на скрине)

[image: Response Headers]

Но куки не записываются на **https**://localhost:3000, но если напрямую ввести адрес api, то там они записываются

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запрос axios выглядит так

```
axios({
  timeout: 5000,
  method: "GET",
  url: `https://monobrand-api.tarifnik.ru/api/get_phones`,
  data: data,
}, {withCredentials: true}).then(response => response.data)
```

Также добавлял в глобальный конфиг

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
```

Приложение на NextJS / PHP-Laravel. Задача заключается в получении куки из ответа первого запроса, делается он с фронт части, установки их в браузер, а в дальнейшем, любой запрос сайта должен отправить все куки, бэкенд в свою очередь поймет, какая сессия и отправить определенные данные. У Next есть разные возможности реализации своего API и установки заголовков, но думаю в этом нет необходимости. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему так может происходить?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ был найден в одном обсуждении на gitHub. В общем и целом это невозможно. Пришлось редиректить запросы на бэкенде и создавать кастомный дев сервер для разработки. Похоже на костыль, но это работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119). в данном случае лучше было привести текст и ссылку.